# find ip of connected MYSQL database in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, adox

I need to return the ip connection data of an ODBC Mysql connection 
to visually verify that I am connected successfully to the right database on the correct server using VB.net.

In VB6 I used to parse the ADOX.Catalog.ActiveConnection string but that 
does not work in VB.net. No string is returned.

What is the method now used to obtain the IP of a successful ODBC connection?
Searching the ObjectBrowser and MSDN is not helpful in this regard.

not an answer - but more problems

The answer below looked like a drop dead easy way to do it.wish it was this easy.I have been bogged down for hours trying to get the DNS resolved - and running into socket errors on windows7 in the resolve code.

poking about I have come across this MSDN code which is a direct approach from ADOX. However it will not compile as it chokes on compiling ConnectionStringSettings protesting that it is not defined even though it is a member of the System.Net.Configuration assembly. What is wrong with the ADOX syntax.

and I used to think vb coding was easier than java! One would have thought MSDN would have given examples of code that compiled.

```
Imports System.Net

Private Shared Function GetConnectionStringByName(ByVal name As String) As String
    GetConnectionStringByName = "OK"
    ' Assume failure 
    Dim returnValue As String = Nothing

    ' Look for the name in the connectionStrings section. 
    Dim settings As ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySql")

    ' If found, return the connection string. 
    If Not settings Is Nothing Then
        returnValue = settings.ConnectionString()
    End If

    ' Return returnValue
End Function
```

Comment: If you want to just know which server you are connected then you can query mysql to get the hostname `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'hostname'` it returns the host name of the server (this won't return IP though).You can resolve this to find the IP of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the sql query,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'hostname'
```

This will return the hostname of the MySQL server. You can easily resolve the IP from the host name using [Dns.Resolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.net.dns.resolve.aspx)

References:

1. [13.7.5.41 SHOW VARIABLES
   Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-variables.html)
2. [5.1.4 Server System
    Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html)